# Java While Loop - Output Doesn't Show

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, while-loop, output

I am a complete beginner at Java, and I have encountered a problem with the While loops. I just started them, so to practice I copied the example code into Eclipse and tried to run it, but there is no output (code below).

I tried debugging it, so I searched for instructions and tutorials online. I get to the part where I am in the debugging view, and when I'm trying to run the While loop, nothing happens. I click the button to Step into, as all the instruction say, and there should be some output shown there, but there just isn't. Can someone help me with that? How can I get an output from that code? I tried it in Eclipse and TextPad text editor. The program complies okay, but when I run it there is no output.

[Debugging view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn1bF.png)

[After clicking step into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OveQR.png)

[Code Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT56U.png)

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int value = 1;

    while (value<10);
    {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
        value=value+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: VTC typo. `while (value<10);` remove the semicolon. It terminates the loop body. So you have an infinite loop followed by an unconnected block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` doesn't loops because you've inserted a semicolon `;` after the while loop declaration.

You have to remove it to make your loop able to enter in its scope, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int value = 1;

    while (value<10) {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
        value=value+1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the ; by while (value<10) than it should work